# How can I set up Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to automatically empty the trash based on parameters?

Tags: 16.04, delete, trash

There is a way to periodically blindly empty the trash on a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS system for a specific user.

Start with a script that contains the following lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*
```

then use cron to have it run on a periodic basis.

(In fact, this works under Raspbian and other versions of Debian, also)

---

But what if it would be preferable to keep files for xx days, or until free space drops below yy, or some other parameter?

The question is in the title:  How can I set up Ubuntu 16.04 to automatically empty the trash based on parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out there is a program called autotrash that works under Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Here is an article that describes how it works:

[Automatically Empty the Trash in Ubuntu](http://helpdeskgeek.com/linux-tips/automatically-empty-the-trash-in-ubuntu/)

--> This article is informative but is older, so do not follow the install instructions.

Instead, just do this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install autotrash
```

Then the program is executed by entering the autotrash command with arguments.

This can be run periodically by cron, and based on specific parameters:

Those arguments are described in detail in the

[man page for autotrash for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/autotrash.1.html)

EXCERPT:

> NAME
>          autotrash   —  program to automatically purge old files from the trash
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          autotrash [-d purge_n_days_old]

```
   autotrash [--delete number_of_megabytes_to_purge]

   autotrash [--keep-free number_of_megabytes_to_free]
```

> DESCRIPTION
>          autotrash is a program that looks in a FreeDesktop.org Trash folder for
>          information  on  it's  contents  and  then  purges  a part of the trash
>          depending on the options.

```
   The most common option is -d, which will purge files that have been  in
   the trash for more then a given number of days.

   The  option --delete will remove at least the given number of megabytes
   from the trash, removing the oldest trash first.

   Using --keep-free will make sure at least the given number of megabytes
   of  free  space  is available, by automatically setting --delete to the
   right value. For example, to  keep  at  least  a  1GB  of  free  space,
   removing files from the trash if needed, use autotrash --keep-free 1024
```

The man page goes on to describe many other options.

Comment: Except autotrash is broken with a parse error for the time stamps...   "ValueError: unconverted data remains"