# How to automatically empty trash periodically?

Tags: delete, trash

I discovered this post [How can I set up Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to automatically empty the trash based on parameters?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/940917/how-can-i-set-up-ubuntu-16-04-lts-to-automatically-empty-the-trash-based-on-para)

Does autotrash itself runs automatically?

If not, how to config it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the project [sources and `README.md` up on Github](https://github.com/bneijt/autotrash), you'll read that in order to run this Python script regularly, you can either:

- Create a `crontab` entry with some regular interval (e.g., `@daily /usr/bin/autotrash -d 30`)
- Add it to the [`Startup Application`](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html) program so `autotrash` can run every time you boot your system.

For additional configuration details, [refer to the Ubuntu Manpage for autotrash](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man1/autotrash.1.html).

Comment: To install autotrash if you already have Python and Pip installed, simply run `pip3 install --user autotrash`. If your path includes `$HOME/.local/bin` you can run it directly from the terminal

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in the old fashion way with Terminal,

> $ sudo crontab -e

Add these lines in the **Crontab**,

> @reboot find /home/**yourname**/.local/share/Trash/expunged/ -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
>
> @reboot find /home/**yourname**/.local/share/Trash/files/ -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
>
> @reboot find /home/**yourname**/.local/share/Trash/info/ -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;

The **-mtime** is set to 30 days. The commands above will check and delete files that over 30 days old at system startup. Hope this will help.